# UART communication - AVR C to Raspberry Pi 2 Python

Tags: pi-2, uart, wiringpi

I am still a Raspberry Pi newbie.

I am using an Atmega32 to transmit data to a Raspberry Pi 2 via UART. The Atmega transmission code is in C and the RPi receiving code is in Python 2.7. Below is the Atmega C code. I use the function USART_Transmit_String(), which calls uart_putc() in the Atmega.

```
int uart_putc(unsigned char c) 
{
    while(!UCSRA & (1<<UDRE))
    {}
    UDR = c;
    return 0;
}

void USART_Transmit_String(char *s) // *s = Technolo
{
    while(*s)
    {
        uart_putc(*s);
        s++
    }
}
```

Now for the Rpi I tried both pyserial and wiringpi methods of recieving data.
With pyserial I noticed that the ser.read(x) require a python str type (string). With wiringpi I noticed that the function wiringpi.serialGetchar(x) can recieve a one char instead of an array of chars such as *s. For both methods I was unable to recieve data from *s. For both methods I was unable to read the transitted data on the RPi terminal.

For pyserial I used :

```
import time
import os 
import serial
os.system('clear')
ser = serial.Serial (
    "/dev/ttyAMA0",
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)                    

    readData1 = ser.read(8)                    
    print readData1
    time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

For wiringpi :

```
import wiringpi as wiringpi
import os 
os.system('clear')
wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()
serial = wiringpi.serialOpen('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)

while 1:
    readValue = wiringpi.serialGetchar(serial) ;
    print readValue
```

Please help with any suggestions, even if you know of any other method to transmit data from Atmega32 to RPi2 preferably using UART. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have asked several questions, which means you are unlikely to get any helpful response. For a start you should ask Arduino questions on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions **Why** are you trying to write your own Arduino code when it already has perfectly adequate serial functionality? I suggest you start with the Examples e.g. AnalogReadSerial to get that working **first** then ask a Pi question.

Comment: @Milliways He didn't even write it's an Arduino. There are tousands of Atmega32 boards and devices out there. @Sesethu It's hard to debug both sides the same time. I suggest to verify the Atmega side first by using standard tools on Pi side, like `screen /dev/ttyAMA0 9600`

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ATmega initialization code? Have you verified the baud rate to be the same?

What about the wiring?
Depending on the Pi model, it may vary (also keep an eye on the different peripherals e.g. mini-UART)

```
#define UBRR_VAL ((F_CPU+BAUD*8)/(BAUD*16)-1)
#define BAUD_REAL (F_CPU/(16*(UBRR_VAL+1)))  
void uart_init(void)
{
    UBRR1H = UBRR_VAL >> 8;
    UBRR1L = UBRR_VAL & 0xFF;

    UCSR1B |= (1<<TXEN1) | (1<<RXEN1);  // UART TX/RX enable
    UCSR1C = (1<<USBS1)|(3<<UCSZ00);    //8N1
}
```

Note that the BAUD_REAL define may be used for error checking (=difference to expected baud rate).

Btw, are you sure your code even compiles? There are several syntax issues in both, AVR and Pi Code.

Comment: Hi @Milliways, I am using an Atmega32 microcontroller not Arduino.

Comment: @Philippos the code does compile and the two parts work  perfectly when not integrated. I can send UART data to my laptop terminal with the Atmega and I tested the RPi by connecting the UART Tx and Rx pins together and I receive what I am sending. I also verified the baud rate and the stopbits. They are the same.